# Find complete id using partial ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am stuck in situation where i need to find complete id using partial id in **jQuery.** Suppose i have below HTML element

```
       <div id="Partial_Known_Id">
          <span>
          </span>
       </div>
```

How do i fetch full id of above element using partial id?

Suppose i know that it begins with **Partial_**. 
I have tried below

```
var b = $('[id*="Partial_"]');
```

But it does not seem to work.

Anyway i can get full id in some variable??

Comment: in general is simpler to use a common class. WHat are you trying to do , code shown should find that element

Comment: If you want the id then `var b = $('[id*="Partial_"]').attr('id');` because `$('[id*="Partial_"]')` return a jQuery object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know *all* of their `id`s, you'll need a loop, e.g.:

```
var b = $('[id*="Partial_"]');
b.each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

That loop can be in your code (as above), or in jQuery's code:

```
var ids = $('[id*="Partial_"]').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

That latter gives you an array of the matching `id`s.

Note that if you **know** the `id` *starts with* "Partial_", you can use `^=` rather than `*=`. `*=` will match the string *anywhere*; `^=` will only match it at the beginning of the `id`.

Live example of both `each` and `map`:

```js
var b = $('[id*="Partial_"]');
snippet.log(b.length + " found using `*=`:");
b.each(function() {
  snippet.log(this.id);
});

snippet.log("As an array: " + b.map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get().join(", "));

snippet.log("---");

b = $('[id^="Partial_"]');
snippet.log(b.length + " found using `^=`:");
b.each(function() {
  snippet.log(this.id);
});

snippet.log("As an array: " + b.map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get().join(", "));
```

```html
<div id="Partial_1"></div>
<div id="Partial_2"></div>
<div id="Partial_3"></div>
<div id="blah_Partial_foo"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.attr()`:

```
var b = $('[id^="Partial_"]').attr('id');
```

`*` seems to be slower, so better to use `^` caret sign which denotes *start with*.

Comment: will always return id of first element within collection

Answer (score -1):

You're using the wrong selector.

```
var b = $('[id^="Partial_"]').attr('id');
```

Check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for more info.